# How to add an Image Input in React that pushes to Firebase with other inputs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app which allows me to post projects with their name, description and image. So far I have been successful in making the name and description posting part getting to work. The problem i'm having is with the image upload. I am uploading it to storage but can't seem to figure out a method to link that reference with firestore. I have tried making a reference field in my firestore collection which writes the location of the image but it shows underfined when posted. Any help would be appreciated. I am linking my code below.

App.js

```
function App() {
  
  const[name, setName] = useState("")
  const[description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const[imageUpload,setImageUpload] = useState(null)


  const projectsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'project')

  const uploadImage = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault()

   

    const image = String(imageUpload.name)
    const imageName = `images/${imageUpload.name}`
    if (imageUpload == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imageName)
    uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then(()=>{
      alert(
        "done"
      )
    })


    const createDoc = async() =>{
      await addDoc(projectsCollectionRef, {name: name, description: description, image: imageName})
    }

    createDoc()
  }

  
  return (


    <div className="App">
      <div className="form">
        <form action="" onSubmit={uploadImage}>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Name:' onChange={(e) =>{setName(e.target.value)}}/>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Description:' onChange={(e) =>{setDescription(e.target.value)}}/>
          <input type="file" name="" onChange={(e) =>{setImageUpload(e.target.files)}} id="" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[firebase output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohp8n.png)

I have tried to look for tutorials or articles that target this issue but no one seems to be applying this kind of logic. They usually just show how to upload images and thats it.

Comment: Hello, If you wish to insert an image onto Firestore or Firebase real-time db, I would suggest you   Encode it Using Something Like Base64 Encoder and insert the encoded value to the field. or else you could try to upload the image to Firebase storage first then add the Url path of the image to Firestore.

Comment: thanks for the help. if you don;t mind can you please link any articles that show how to do this. much appreciated